# How to stop importing csv data?

Tags: postgresql

How do I tell postgres to stop importing data when the last row has been imported?

I defined my primary key with not null constraint. My rows ends at 1452. I get the error:

```
     ERROR:  null value in column "coachiid" violates not-null constraint
     DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).
     CONTEXT:  COPY coaches, line 1453: ";;;;;;;;;;"
```

For obvious reasons postgres thinks that it violates the constaints. However my open office csv table just ends there. Is there a trick or way to indicate that?

I suppose its more an OpenOffice issue than of postgres. Perhaps someone had similar experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL copy's command cannot handle constraints violations.

You are right, i think it's better to consider that OpenOffice's issue and process file before import data. Or to use a temp table.

But, if you prefere, and if we can identify the last line as a row with all field set to null, you can achieve the ignoring the last line by a trigger as bellow:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cancel_if_empty_row()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$begin

if tg_op='INSERT' and new.coachiid is  null and new.field2 is null and new.field3 null and new.field4 is null then
return null;
end if;

return new;

end;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_cancel_if_empty_row
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE cancel_if_empty_row();
```

[WIKI: COPY command](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY)

[COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)